# Apache htaccess 301 Redirect to New Filename Pattern?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have come up with a snippet of code that might convert an existing filename pattern to a new one:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*)-pi-(.*)\.html$ $1-p-$2 [NE,R]
```

Before I go messing around on the server, would offer some advice or a better solution?

I am hoping to redirect files looking for url containing "-pi-" to "-p-".

**From** - http: //www.p.com/great-product-pi-37.html
 **To** - 
http: //www.p.com/great-product-p-37.html

The *product name* (great-product) and *product id* (37) change for every product, but the format remains the same.

The -pi- reference used to be a pop-up window to a generated image. The image is now displayed on the same -p- screen, but search engines keep indexing and searching for the old -pi- image windows.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should work with small tweaks, but you need to use a `301` redirect also. If you just use `[R]` without specifying `301` it defaults to `302`. You don't want temporary. You want permanent. I would put this above the other rewrites you might have.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)-pi-(.+)\.html$ /$1-p-$2.html [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Works beautifully! I also add the "?" the the output to remove additional query information.

Comment: Looks like this:
RewriteRule ^(.+)-pi-(.+)\.html$ /$1-p-$2.html? [R=301,L]

Comment: Why do you use "+" instead of "*"?

Comment: Because * is greedy. + means 1 or more so you only want it to match if there is an actual value. Example. If someone enters `example.com/-pi-.html` it will still try to redirect that to `example.com/-p-.html`. The plus makes it so it can't be an empty value. So only `example.com/something-pi-here.html` will work and redirect.

Comment: Super explanation! Most online examples seem to use the *, but it defiantly makes more sense to +, for most situations.